# Why is the SVG text not spins in place?

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, rotation, svg-animate

So I have this code:

```css
#ring-svg {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100svw;
  height: 100svh;
  background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
}

.alt-font {
  font-family: "TnganAlt";
}

#textcircle {
  fill: rgb(35, 35, 35);
}

.textPath {
  fill: wheat;
}

#textcircle:hover+.text-circle-inside .textPath {
  fill: red;
  transition: fill 2s ease;
}

#textcircle:hover+.text-circle-inside {
  animation: spinText 10s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes spinText {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.zsap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" id="ring-svg">
  <path id="textcircle" d="M250,400 a150,150 0 0,1 0,-350 a150,150 0 0,1 0,350 Z"/>
  <text font-family="Tngan" font-size="20" class="text-circle-inside">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle" ariaLabel="CSS &amp; SVG are awesome" textLength="1090" class="textPath" transform="rotate(0)" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
    <tspan class="alt-font">&nbsp;»</tspan>AE5,Dx26Hw1E<tspan class="alt-font">j</tspan>^z<tspan class="alt-font">H</tspan>= AE5,DxxwP%1Ej^<tspan class="alt-font">«&nbsp;</tspan>AE5,Dx37zD1E<tspan class="alt-font">j</tspan>^z<tspan class="alt-font">H</tspan>= X#w6HktYAT`Bz7qpT1Ej^</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

When you hover over the circle it should spin the text in place. It almost working but its start to go a little down and to the right.

Is it because the text is not a perfect circle from the start? or should I use different method the make it spin?

Comment: Instead of `transform-origin: center;` try using `transform-origin: 250px 225px;` As you have it now the center is 250 250. Also it is preferable to add the code to the question.

Comment: @enxaneta aw man awesome it works, how did you find out?

Comment: You need to get the center of the path. In JS you can calculate the bounding box of an svg shape using getBBox(). This will return an object (I name it bb) with the position (x y) 
 and the size (width & height) of the bounding box. The center of the path is x = bb.x + bb.width/2 and y = bb.y + bb.height/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often (specially when combining SVG presentation attributes and CSS -- and also in general) it is easier to place elements centered around 0,0. So, here I moved the path, so that the center is 0,0 and then use transform/translate to place the entire thing centered in the SVG.

```css
#ring-svg {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100svw;
  height: 100svh;
  background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
}

.alt-font {
  font-family: "TnganAlt";
}

#textcircle {
  fill: rgb(35, 35, 35);
}

.textPath {
  fill: wheat;
}

#textcircle:hover+.text-circle-inside .textPath {
  fill: red;
  transition: fill 2s ease;
}

#textcircle:hover+.text-circle-inside {
  animation: spinText 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinText {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.zsap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" id="ring-svg">
  <g transform="translate(250 250)">
    <path id="textcircle" d="M 0 175 a 150 150 0 0 1 0 -350 a 150 150 0 0 1 0 350 Z" pathLength="500"/>
    <text font-family="Tngan" font-size="20" class="text-circle-inside">
      <textPath href="#textcircle" textLength="1090" class="textPath" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
      <tspan class="alt-font">&nbsp;»</tspan>AE5,Dx26Hw1E<tspan class="alt-font">j</tspan>^z<tspan class="alt-font">H</tspan>= AE5,DxxwP%1Ej^<tspan class="alt-font">«&nbsp;</tspan>AE5,Dx37zD1E<tspan class="alt-font">j</tspan>^z<tspan class="alt-font">H</tspan>= X#w6HktYAT`Bz7qpT1Ej^</textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```